# Work done in a Vector Field / Green's Theorem with Parametrization

Tags: calculus, integration, vectors, greens-theorem

I have a question that states:
Calculate the work done by the vector field
$$F = y^3 \hat{i} + 3xy^2 \hat{j}$$
A parametrized version is given as

$$x(t) = cos(t) +\frac{1}{4}sin(5t)^2$$
$$y(t) = sin(t)$$
$$t = 0... 2 \pi$$

I originally began by using Green's theorem,

Work = $\int F_xdx + F_ydy$

W = $\int Pdx + Qdy$

W = $\int y^3dx + 3xy^2dy$

Solving for $dx$ and $dy$ gave me...

$ dx = -sin(t) + \frac{5}{2}sin(5t)dt$

$dy= cos(t)dt$

I then attempted to input the equations with relation to $t$...

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} sin(t)^3(-sin(t) + 5/2sin(5t))dt + 3(cos(t) + 1/4sin(5t)^2)sin(t)^2cos(t)dt$

However, this integral seems extremely complex and I want to be sure I have the correct idea before proceeding.  Is there another method that might be more effective to implement?

Answer (score 0):

So did you try using Green's Theorem, which is in your title? What is $\displaystyle{\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}}$? (Note that the curve is a simple closed curve.)